# Split a list of elements into multiple columns with Key - Value

Tags: r, split, tidyr

Working with large dataframe with a string that is a list of elements (as chr). I want to separate the string so that each element has its own column with key - value. I tried 'tidyr::seperate' and 'tidyverse::unnest_wider()' but none of them returned my desired output.

Here is a dummy data :

```
  df1 <- tibble(
    id = c('000914', '000916'),
    code = c('NN', 'SS'),
    values2 = c("{DS=15}{FPLUC=0}{N=CELL}{R=NINT1}{S=true}{SPLUC=1}" , "{DS=0}{FPLUC=0}{N=CELL}{R=NINT1}{S=true}{SPLUC=1}"         
  ) )

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  id     code  values2                                           
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>                                             
1 000914 NN    {DS=15}{FPLUC=0}{N=CELL}{R=NINT1}{S=true}{SPLUC=1}
2 000916 SS    {DS=0}{FPLUC=0}{N=CELL}{R=NINT1}{S=true}{SPLUC=1}
```

I tried with separate, this is not wrong but it is not exactly what I am looking for and it needs several pivot_longer and pivot_wider for reshaping. Is there any better and faster alternative?

```
  df1 %>% 
    separate(values2, into = paste("Col", 1:14)) 

# A tibble: 2 x 16
  id     code  `Col 1` `Col 2` `Col 3` `Col 4` `Col 5` `Col 6` `Col 7` `Col 8` `Col 9`
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 000914 NN    ""      DS      15      FPLUC   0       N       CELL    R       NINT1  
2 000916 SS    ""      DS      0       FPLUC   0       N       CELL    R       NINT1  
# ... with 5 more variables: Col 10 <chr>, Col 11 <chr>, Col 12 <chr>, Col 13 <chr>,
#   Col 14 <chr>
```

Here is my desired output:

```
  id     code   DS    FPLUC   N          R      S     SPLUC 

1 000914 NN    15     0      CELL       NINT1   true       1         
2 000916 SS    0      0      CELL       NINT1   true       1
```

---

Alternative solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(values2 = str_remove(values2, "{"),
         values2 = str_remove(values2, "}")) %>% 
  tidyr::extract(values2, 
                 c("DS", "FPLUC", "N", "R", "S", "SPLUC"), 
                 "(.*?)=(.*?)", 
                 extra = "drop")
```

The regular expression "(.*?)=(.*?)" matches the text between = signs, capturing the key and the value as separate groups. The c("DS", "FPLUC", "N", "R", "S", "SPLUC") argument specifies the names of the new columns that will be created based on the extracted key-value pairs. The extra = "drop" argument drops any unmatched text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure `tidyr` solution:

```r
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  separate_rows(values2, sep = '(?<=\\})(?=\\{)') %>%
  extract(values2, c('name', 'value'), '\\{(.+?)=(.+?)\\}') %>%
  pivot_wider()

# # A tibble: 2 × 8
#   id     code  DS    FPLUC N     R     S     SPLUC
#   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 000914 NN    15    0     CELL  NINT1 true  1
# 2 000916 SS    0     0     CELL  NINT1 true  1
```

- `separate_rows()` separates a collapsed column (`values2`) into multiple rows. The separator `(?<=\\})(?=\\{)` locates the position between `}` and `{`.
- `extract()` separates a character column into multiple columns using regular expression groups. The regex `\\{(.+?)=(.+?)\\}` searches the pattern `{Col=Value}` and extracts `Col` and `Value` respectivly as new columns.

Comment: Great, that's exactly I was looking for, would you mind explaining a bit the meaning of regex that you used

Comment: @DanG You could check my update!

Answer (score 1):

It's messy but you may try

```
library(tidverse)

nms <- str_extract_all(df1$values2[1], "(?<=\\{).+?(?=\\=)", simplify = T)
nms <- c(names(df1)[-3],nms)
df1 %>%
  mutate(values2 = str_extract_all(values2, "(?<=\\=).+?(?=\\})")) %>%
  unnest_wider(values2, names_repair = ~nms) 

  id     code  DS    FPLUC N     R     S     SPLUC
  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 000914 NN    15    0     CELL  NINT1 true  1    
2 000916 SS    0     0     CELL  NINT1 true  1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not so keen on the REGEX, try the following

```r
library(dplyr, quietly=TRUE, warn.conflicts=FALSE)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.1.3
library(tidyr)

df1 <- tibble(
  id = c('000914', '000916'),
  code = c('NN', 'SS'),
  values2 = c("{DS=15}{FPLUC=0}{N=CELL}{R=NINT1}{S=true}{SPLUC=1}" , "{DS=0}{FPLUC=0}{N=CELL}{R=NINT1}{S=true}{SPLUC=1}"         
  ) )

df1 
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   id     code  values2                                           
#>   <chr>  <chr> <chr>                                             
#> 1 000914 NN    {DS=15}{FPLUC=0}{N=CELL}{R=NINT1}{S=true}{SPLUC=1}
#> 2 000916 SS    {DS=0}{FPLUC=0}{N=CELL}{R=NINT1}{S=true}{SPLUC=1}

df1 %>% 
  mutate(values2 = stringr::str_remove_all(values2, "\\}")) %>% # remove the } from values 2
  separate(values2, into = c("X","DS","FPLUC","N","R","S","SPLUC"), sep = "{") %>% # split values 2 into required columns
  mutate(across(.cols = c(DS, FPLUC, N, R, S, SPLUC), 
                .fns = ~stringr::str_remove(.x, "^.+="))) %>% #remove "xxx=" from each of the columns
  select(!X) # keep all columns except X as it is empty
#> # A tibble: 2 x 8
#>   id     code  DS    FPLUC N     R     S     SPLUC
#>   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 000914 NN    15    0     CELL  NINT1 true  1    
#> 2 000916 SS    0     0     CELL  NINT1 true  1
```